# Java collection wildcard with multiple bounds (implements interface and extends class)

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Is something like this possible?

```
public class TypedPreferenceScreen<T> {
    private ArrayList<? super Preference extends TypedPreference<T>> childPrefs;
}
```

Comment: Today, you learn about [**PECS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't you have multiple interfaces in a bounded wildcard generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643241/why-cant-you-have-multiple-interfaces-in-a-bounded-wildcard-generic)

Comment: It's true that there is no way to do this currently but I don't think the answers at that duplicate are great. Both of the most upvoted answers are wrong now. Type inference does handle intersection types and there is a way to write intersection types as part of a program (currently I think only as a cast expression).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to specify both upper and lower bound constraints on type parameters in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530563/is-it-possible-to-specify-both-upper-and-lower-bound-constraints-on-type-paramet)

Comment: @radiodef can you go into more detail/specifics?

Comment: I don't think there is really much more detail to go in to. Type inference went through an overhaul in Java 8 to make it better at stuff like this but it's still somewhat limited and I'd expect them to update it again in a future version. The addition of intersection types in a cast is currently only useful when specifying a lambda target type, generally for the purpose of making a lambda serializiable ([example](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Comparator.java#Comparator.comparing%28java.util.function.Function%29)).